VBA Code throws errors that I cannot figure out
I have table where I track documents that have been created and documents that have been requested to be created. For the new documents I assign a control number, but I can't see it clearly enough to avoid repeating the numbers, so I am trying to separate the different types of documents out and further split them based on the type of device being documented and the specific subject being documented. I also need the numbers that are not sequential to leave a blank space, as the control numbers need to stay the same across each device only differentiating by the device unique identifier. I have defined what each part of the control number designates in my code and assigned a column for each truck/subject combination.
Sub AssignValuesAndCopy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim firstPart As String
    Dim middlePart As String
    Dim lastPart As String
    Dim assignedValue As String
    Dim otherItem As String
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetColumn As Long
    Dim sequentialStart As Long

    ' Set the worksheet (change "Sheet2" to your actual sheet name)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Documents")

    ' Find the last used row in column B
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Set sourceCell = ws.Cells(i, 2) ' Column B

   parts = Split(sourceCell.Value, "-")
 ' Extract the first, middle, and last parts
    firstPart = Split(sourceCell.Value, "-")(0)
        ' Extract the middle part (if it exists)
        If UBound(parts) >= 1 Then
            middlePart = parts(1)
        Else
            middlePart = "" ' Handle cases where there is no middle part
        End If
    ' Extract the last part (if it exists)
        If UBound(parts) >= 2 Then
            lastPart = parts(2)
        Else
            lastPart = "" ' Handle cases where there is no last part
        End If

    ' Assign values based on the first part
    Select Case firstPart
        Case "INS"
            assignedValue = "INS"
        Case "RTF"
            assignedValue = "RTF"
        Case "SFT"
            assignedValue = "SFT"
        Case "SPT"
            assignedValue = "SPT"
        Case "SVC"
            assignedValue = "SVC"
        Case "TNG"
            assignedValue = "TNG"
        Case "TST"
            assignedValue = "TST"
        Case "WKI"
            assignedValue = "WKI"
        
    End Select
    
    ' Assign values based on the middle part
    Select Case middlePart
        Case "T20"
            assignedValue = "1"
        Case "D20"
            assignedValue = "2"
        Case "H20"
            assignedValue = "3"
        Case "T23"
            assignedValue = "5"
        Case "D23"
            assignedValue = "6"
        Case "H23"
            assignedValue = "7"
        Case "T26"
            assignedValue = "9"
        Case "D26"
            assignedValue = "10"
        Case "H26"
            assignedValue = "11"
        Case "T28"
            assignedValue = "13"
        Case "D28"
            assignedValue = "14"
        Case "H28"
            assignedValue = "15"
        Case "T30"
            assignedValue = "17"
        Case "D30"
            assignedValue = "18"
        Case "H30"
            assignedValue = "19"
        Case "T38"
            assignedValue = "21"
        Case "D38"
            assignedValue = "22"
        Case "H38"
            assignedValue = "23"
        Case "T53"
            assignedValue = "25"
        Case "D53"
            assignedValue = "26"
        Case "H53"
            assignedValue = "27"
        Case "T56"
            assignedValue = "29"
        Case "D56"
            assignedValue = "30"
        Case "H56"
            assignedValue = "31"
        Case "T60"
            assignedValue = "33"
        Case "D60"
            assignedValue = "34"
        Case "H60"
            assignedValue = "35"
        Case "T61"
            assignedValue = "37"
        Case "D61"
            assignedValue = "38"
        Case "H61"
            assignedValue = "39"
        Case "T62"
            assignedValue = "41"
        Case "D62"
            assignedValue = "42"
        Case "H62"
            assignedValue = "43"
        Case "T65"
            assignedValue = "45"
        Case "D65"
            assignedValue = "46"
        Case "H65"
            assignedValue = "47"
        Case "T66"
            assignedValue = "49"
        Case "D66"
            assignedValue = "50"
        Case "H66"
            assignedValue = "51"
        Case "T70"
            assignedValue = "52"
        Case "D70"
            assignedValue = "53"
        Case "H70"
            assignedValue = "54"
        Case "T80"
            assignedValue = "5"
        Case "D80"
            assignedValue = "58"
        Case "H80"
            assignedValue = "59"
    End Select
  
    ' Determine the target sheet based on the first value
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(firstPart) ' Assumes sheet names match assigned values

    ' Set the target column (e.g., column B)
    targetColumn = Val(middlePart)

    ' Copy the assigned value to the specified target sheet and column
    targetSheet.Cells(1, targetColumn).Value = assignedValue
Next i
   
    MsgBox "Values assigned and copied successfully!"
End Sub


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBSRZJUf.jpg


Please specify the error message and the line that throws the error.

A couple things... 1)  you have an entire select based on assignedValue = Split(sourceCell.Value, "-")(0), so you shouldn't need to have those cases at all.  2) Your middlepart can be a dictionary, and you output the value of dictionary.  Regarding the "blanks" required, that is its own discussion, as it may very well need an image or mock-up of your desired output (and image of input data)

the error is Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range at
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(firstPart) ' Assumes sheet names match assigned values

Then there's no sheet corresponding to that value of firstPart in this workbook. In other words, sheet names match assigned values is false.

I will try the dictionary approach as I cannot figure out how to upload an image.  regarding the blanks, INS-T20-0001 Inspection Document XXXX, and INS-T20-0003 Inspection Document XXX, where the gap in those two documents is a placeholder as INS-D20-0001, INS-D20-0002, and INS-D20-0003 exist. The goal is to keep similar content documents on the same suffix across all devices.

@AidanL you can use win+shift+s to screen snip and that can be pasted into your post (edit the post)

@Cyril, I cannot embed images yet, I don't have enough reputation.

@BigBen, the sheets are exactly as defined. I copied and pasted them from the title of the sheets.

That's the only reason you can get that error. It might help to Debug.Print firstPart and inspect the output in the Immediate Window.

@AidanL, you can add an image as a link. Moderators may edit you question to make the image embedded.

Dictionary fixed my problem! Thank you to all who responded.
